# Install vue 3.0 in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vuejs3

Is there a way to install vue 3.0 to Laravel 8? When I run

```
npm install vue@next
```

It started installing Vue 3.0, but for some reason it also began installing `vue-template-compiler` v2.6.12. The following appears:

> ```
>     Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.
>
>     Running: npm install vue-template-compiler --save-dev --production=false
> ```

And then when I run

```
npm run dev
```

The following error appears:

> - vue@3.0.0 (C:\wamp64\www\vue-sample\node_modules\vue\index.js)
> - vue-template-compiler@2.6.12 (C:\wamp64\www\vue-sample\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\package.json)
>
> This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same
> version for both. If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update
> vue-template-compiler. If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify,
> re-installing vue-loader/vueify should bump vue-template-compiler to
> the latest.
>
> @ ./resources/js/app.js 19:35-79  @ multi ./resources/js/app.js
> ./resources/sass/app.scss

I am completely new in Vue. What should I do?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

****Update 2022****

[image]

For those who prefer [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/), there's a tool called [Laravel Vite](https://laravel-vite.dev/) which is a project based on PHP package, Vite plugin and preset, you could install it as follows :

```
npx @preset/cli apply laravel:vite
```

This removes the default config in the Laravel fresh project.

For further details please check the different section in official [docs](https://laravel-vite.dev/)

---

**Update October 2020**

Now with [`laravel-mix v6`](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) you could run Vue 3 code in Laravel App:

**1. Installation :**

```
npm i -D laravel-mix@next vue@next @vue/compiler-sfc vue-loader@next
```

then

```
npm i
```

before doing that try to **remove** the following dependencies from `package.json` which some of them are added by `php artisan ui vue` :

- `vue`
- `vue-template-compiler`
- `laravel-mix`

**2. Config:**

in the `package.json` change the scripts to the following ones:

```
"scripts": {
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "production": "mix --production"
}
```

`webpack.mix.js` should contain :

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue();
```

The minimum content of `resources/js/app.js`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './components/App.vue'
createApp(App).mount("#app")
```

In order to avoid this confusing steps  clone this **[REPOSITORY](https://github.com/boussadjra/laravel-vue-3-starter)** and start coding.

**OLD ANSWER**

Laravel doesn't support vue 3 yet, but you could try out [laravel-mix-vue3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-mix-vue3) :

**Installation** :

```
npm install @types/webpack-env @vue/compiler-sfc vue-loader@next laravel-mix-vue3  --save-dev
```

**Usage** :

Configure in `webpack.mix.js` as follows :

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

require("laravel-mix-vue3");

mix.vue3("resources/js/app.js", "public/js");
```

Answer (score 6):

## Update

Laravel mix v6 is now in beta, use the guide [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) to upgrade and use Vue v3.

### Old answer

You don't need to use the vue3 plugin. I got working as follows:

Install Vue3,  Vue3 loader and the compiler:

```
npm install vue@next vue-loader@next @vue/compiler-sfc
```

Then in your app.js import vue from the esm bundle:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';
```

Then create your app and mount it:

```
createApp({}).mount('#app')
```

Now just build your assets as usual with mix

```
 npm run dev
```

Comment: Hi @Rando can you provide more details?  what version of Laravel mix are you using?  can you share your package.json and your webpack.mix.js files?  Thanks!

Comment: When i wrote this laravel-mix was not updated, now you can use mix6-beta to do this, check this [link](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/UPGRADE.md)

Comment: can you provide more detailed instructions like your package.json and webpack.mix.js files?  I tried following the instructions in your link and it did not work for me, especially when trying to compile an ExampleTest.vue component.  Can you verify you got this to work?  I think Jeffrey's still trying to figure stuff out :)