# Laravel Mix Vuejs component Syntax error on <template />

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

I'm using a Windows 10 OS for development and I created a laravel 8, mix with VueJs project. The file on my `./components/app.vue` is returning a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)`

This is what's inside the app.vue file

```
<template>
    <div>
        Event Calendar VueJs x Laravel
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "App",
    data(){
        return{
            event: "",
            event_from: "",
            event_to: "",
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I also set up this vue component on the `/resources/js/app.js`, here's what it looks like

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from "vue";

import App from "./components/app.vue";

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        App
    }
});
```

`webpack.mix.js file:`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
]);
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^2.6.12"
    }
}
```

I'm at my dead end, I don't get it why `npm run hot` says it's a `SyntaxError`

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the code you have presented.  Have you tried to erase it all and retype from scratch? It could be there's an invisible character in there somewhere.  I assume your laravel mix file has `.vue()`?

Comment: @Daedalus not sure about the `.vue()` on the laravel mix file, where can I find it? I only checked the `webpack.mix.js` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using laravel mix v6 which adds `.vue()` to `mix.js(...)` :

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue({ version: 2 })
   
mix.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
]);
```

for Vue 3 check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967346/install-vue-3-0-in-laravel/63968220#63968220)

Comment: I followed the answer, also your suggestion but then again there's a new error this is what's shown ```\js\app.js is neither a posix nor a windows path, and there is no 'dirname' 
method defined in the file system```

Comment: please check this issue https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/2666