# How do I install a simple version of Vue 3 into a Laravel 8 project?

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-8, vuejs3, laravel-mix-vue3

I want to install Vue 3 into a Laravel 8 project, but I don't want to use something like `laravel/ui` because it adds Bootstrap and a bunch of other stuff I don't want.

I tried `npm i vue@next`, and it installs Vue 3, but when I try to do `import { createApp } from 'vue';` in `app.js`, etc., I get a bunch of Webpack errors on `npm run dev` with Laravel Mix (`"laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",` in `package.json`).

This is the `webpack.mix.js` file I'm using:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
    .extract(['vue'])
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/')
    .vue()
    .version();
```

And I get this error when I run `npm run dev`:

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
(Stack trace here.)
```

Does anyone know how to simply install Vue 3 (without a bunch of additional scaffolding) in Laravel 8? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Laravel mix? If so, what version are you using and can you add the contents of your `webpack.mix.js` file to your post?

Comment: Good points, Rwd. I went ahead and did that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After searching more, I found another SO post with essentially the same question and an answer that worked.

Instead of just doing `npm i vue@next`, I had to do the following instead:

```
npm i -D laravel-mix@next vue@next @vue/compiler-sfc vue-loader@next
```

After that, everything worked as expected.

Here's the SO post I referenced: [Install vue 3.0 in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967346/install-vue-3-0-in-laravel)