# Uncaught TypeError: Vue is undefined error in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

developing vue + Laravel project. but when try to load vue in welcome.blade.php it is not showing content. Then element console uncounted following error message as well
`Uncaught TypeError: Vue is undefined`
My app.js file is like this

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
Vue.component('mainapp', require('./components/mainapp.vue').dafault)
const app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
})
```

what is the problem and how could I fix this matter?

need some solutions

Comment: `.dafault` should be `.default`

Comment: change but still same error here

Comment: Which vue version are using?

Comment: "vue": "^3.2.45" and  "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6", and "vue-loader": "^16.8.3"

Comment: You're using vue 3, and the syntax above will not work, please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63968220/8172857

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim did it but same error here

Comment: @maramodaya please follow the steps there to create your project

Comment: So `window.Vue` becomes `Vue` magically? Since when? Drop the `window.` part and try again.

Answer (score 0):

if Vue is undefined, usually its because you have not import Vue correctly, have you import vue? can you give more of your code snippet

Comment: what code do you need to show?

Comment: You can ask in comment box for clarification  if you need, Then properly answer the question.